# Run calulations after all input received

Tags: python-3.x

I almost have this application working as needed, I am not sure about how to approach the final result.

**Problem**

I want to receive input from the user and I want calculate the results after all the input is entered.

This is all working with numbers, and  the process would be:

- First input would be the number of tests to calculate the result
- Second input would be the number of digits to be used for the first test
- Third input would be the actual array of numbers used for the calculation
- Fourth input would be the number of digits to be used for second test
- Fifth input would be the actual array of numbers used for the calculation

and so on.....

**For example**

- **3** - The number of tests to be ran
- **4** - Number of digits to be used in the first test
- **4 51 6 1** - Numbers to be used for the calculation
- **3** - Number of digits to be used in the second test
- **7 10 9** - Numbers to be used for the calculation
- **5** - Number of digits to be used in the third test
- **45 2 6 7 9** - Numbers to be used for the calculation

My goal is after collecting all the input above from the user I would like to show the results of the tests which would be this:

- **2654**
- **230**
- **2195**

Here are my code snippets:

```
def run_sum_squared(dta):
    """ run the sum squared calculation"""
    if not dta:
        return 0
    value = int(dta[0])
    if value < 0:
        value = 0
    return value**2 + run_sum_squared(dta[1:])


def do_work(input_num):
    """ get inpute and calculate the numbers"""
    count_input = int(input())
    print(run_sum_squared(input().split()))
    if input_num > 1:
        do_work(input_num - 1)


def main():
    """ Run the Application"""
    input_num = int(input())
    do_work(input_num)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It does the calculations as expected but the results are displayed on the next line like this:

```
3
4
4 51 6 1
2654
3
7 10 9
230
5
45 2 6 7 9
2195
```

I am not too sure what I am missing to just display the results like this

```
2654
230
2195
```

Comment: You are missing to *collect* all user inputs in a data structure before starting the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nature of recursions. You are getting results because you are printing during collection and calculation. If you want to print results last create a mutable object like lists and append your results during calculation.  Finally, print them all together.

```
def run_sum_squared(dta):
    """ run the sum squared calculation"""
    if not dta:
        return 0
    value = int(dta[0])
    if value < 0:
        value = 0
    return value**2 + run_sum_squared(dta[1:])


def do_work(input_num, results):
    """ get inpute and calculate the numbers"""
    count_input = int(input())
    results.append(run_sum_squared(input().split()))
    if input_num > 1:
        do_work(input_num - 1, results)


def main():
    """ Run the Application"""
    input_num = int(input())
    results = []
    do_work(input_num, results)
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

This code calculates results during the input collection but prints them in the end. If you want to make calculations end if collection you can keep data in a list same way.

```
def do_work(input_num, inputs):
    """ get inpute and calculate the numbers"""
    count_input = int(input())
    inputs.append(input().split())
    if input_num > 1:
        do_work(input_num - 1, inputs)


def main():
    """ Run the Application"""
    input_num = int(input())
    inputs = []
    do_work(input_num, inputs)
    results = list(map(run_sum_squared,inputs))
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```